# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Tags: json, angular, plotly, package.json

I recently upgrade the dependencies within my package.json to their latest versions. The dependencies were outdated by atleast 2 years or maybe more. The site i'm working on displays various kinds of graphs and charts and it was working fine before the upgrade to the package.json. What would be the reason for this?

**This is the updated package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "pipeline-viewer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^12.0.0",
    "@wizpanda/super-gif": "0.0.5",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^4.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3", 
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0"
  }
}
```

**This is the old package.json that displays the graphs and charts.**

```json
{
  "name": "pipeline-viewer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@wizpanda/super-gif": "0.0.5",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^1.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "plotly.js": "^1.49.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: what part of your code is causing this problem? sometimes, new versions of some npm packages behave quite differently to previous versions so you need to debug your source code itself

Comment: In the code where i'm using ElementRef from @angular/core it seems like

Comment: using viewChild?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: check my answer may be it will be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's related to viewChild changes in Angular +8

Change

```
@ViewChild('element') element: ElementRef;
```

To

```
@ViewChild('element', {static: true}) element: ElementRef;
// to access your view Child in ngOnInit
```

Same thing for ContentChild

Comment: So if my element was navTable would the substitution be like so?               
@ViewChild('navTable', {static: true}) navTable: ElementRef;

Comment: yes! this is right!

Comment: This works ! Thanks Fateh!